# A country where citizens are supposed to have a name with three to ten parts

Tags: society, near-future, social-norms, names

In my world that is set in a near future, there was an EXTREMELY big country fusion.

Since the country has more than 500 million inhabitants, people are required to have a name with at least three parts, and at most ten parts.

The three required parts are (in order):

1. The given name.
2. The matronymic.
3. The maternal grandmother's surname.

The seven optional parts are (in order) (they all come after the given name, the three last given names and the patronymic comes before the matronymic, and the three other surnames come before the maternal grandmother's surname):

1. The second given name.
2. The third given name.
3. The fourth given name.
4. The patronymic.
5. The paternal grandfather's surname.
6. The paternal grandmother's surname.
7. The maternal grandfather's surname.

For example, a woman is named Fleur Justine Mélanie Dominique Georges Georgette Leblanc Meunier Rivera Williams, and a man is named Vincent Tyler Travis Claude Hugo Olivia Cohen Roberti Thunberg Paulson. If they have a child together, they could be named Maxime Éric Édouard Louis Vincent Fleur Cohen Leblanc Paulson Williams.

So, I wonder if this could be a stable naming convention.

Comment: What does "a stable naming convention" mean in practice?

Comment: There was a rather famous, rich and powerful country where (male) citizens had three part names. Some of those citizens are quite well-known. Marcus Tullius Cicero, Lucius Licinius Lucullus, Marcus Vipsanius Agrippa, Caius Julius Caesar... And the *tria nomina* praenomen-gentilicium-cognomen naming convention was quite stable for several centuries. Additional *agnomina* could be acquired by doing something of valor; you may have heard of Publius Cornelius Scipio Africanus Aemilianus [Numantinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numantine_War).

Comment: There's no requirement for such names in an Information Age society assuming you're looking for unicity. The solution is to give every citizen a unique [number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number). Both real countries with 500 milll+ citizens, China and India, use them.

Comment: P.S. Not to mention Jacques Eliacin François Marie Paganel, or the entire Russian empire. Anna Arkadyevna Karenina, Mikhail Illarionovich Golenishchev-Kutuzov-Smolensky, Natalya Ilyinichna Rostova, Elena Vasilyevna Kuragina, Lev Nikolayevich Myshkin...

Comment: No scheme can completely eliminate the possibility of name collisions, and generally speaking, the more you think you've eliminated that possibility the more catastrophic it will be when one actually happens. (c.f. Douglas Adams and [the difference between](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Chapter_12_4) something that might go wrong and something that *cannot possibly go wrong*)

Comment: Sounds like Iceland and Spain joined together! Since your query is being so soundly beaten down, I would suggest clarifying what your actual worldbuilding *problem* is. The obvious and only really correct answer to this surface level question is a resounding **YES**. Yes, it's a perfectly stable situation. If you put ten labelled boxes on any government form, you're pretty much guaranteed to see those same boxes on any future iteration of all government forms. As asked, however, the question doesn't really explain your motive --- why might you think that the new convention isn't stable? (cont)

Comment: (cont) --- Is the culture of one of the two countries  traditionally monomastic? People who have never heard the concept of having multiple names might (rightly) resist the  requirement of the other country. It's these sorts of unknowns that a) make your question not as good as it could be here and b) are the cause of downvotes and vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

**FRAME CHALLENGE:** Such a society is possible but there are strong biological reason to use a **matrilineality**  as the basis for the naming convention due to the fact that its easy to know and document who the mother of a child is with accuracy and much less so the father, especially over multiple generations.  And to simplify things you might cut it down to just 6 names.

In Judaism for instance Jewish decent in 'mixed couples has apparently been traced through maternal lines since early in the 1st century AD/BCE. Taking that as a baseline if you posited a culture with strong/insular clannish tendencies like medieval Scotland or Japan, one in which your family name was important because it identified your social or financial status, territory of origin, trades & crafts etc (or lots of things mixed together) then you have a basis for names being important.

Add in a dominant role for women in your society for religious or historical reasons and you would have a scenario where something 'like' your naming convention could apply, especially if women partly keep their family names after marriage. For example you could well imagine that formal ceremonies such as marriages, the signing of important contracts or political gatherings etc required attendees to state their full names.

The convention might work something like this. **Fathers are entitled to give their children  three 'given' names**  based on a selection of names from within their lineage or clan. The next three names are **their 'family' name/s  and are based on the clan names of the previous three females in the mothers line**. If or when women marry into a different clan they simply adopt that new clan name and and drop the *last* Clan name from their family name. So someone from Clan 'Smith' who is going to marry into Clan Jones might have had the name  X,X,X, Smith, Brown, Smith. After marriage she becomes X,X,X, Jones Smith Brown.

It would IMO be unnecessarily complicated but technically anyone would know your family links going back 3 generations just from your name. But as I said to simplify things though I think I would go with only 6 names in total. Three given names from the father and three family names from the mother.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if this could be a stable naming convention.

Sure, if people actually knew their lineages and they were registered in detail this would work fine.

Where it falls apart is when people do not know their maternal grandmothers name and suchlike. So you'd need a society with rock solid records going back a few generations and probably DNA paternity tests and anything else that would establish beyond doubt names that can legitimately be claimed within lineages.

These would be legal names and regulated rather than trusting everyone to use the correct ones. So they can be contested for validity etc.